# Language for LLVM-based compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'm looking at doing some initial tests and experiments with a toy language and building an LLVM-based compiler to get some benchmarkable results.

I realize that C++ is LLVM's "native" and best-supported language, but I *really* don't want to use C or C++. So I'm looking for a higher-level language that has stable and established support for working with the LLVM API.

My initial work with the [Python LLVM library](http://code.google.com/p/llvm-py/) was a bit of a disappointment as the project seems to have been abandoned, though I hear promising news about PyPy integrating LLVM support into their framework, but I'd like to know what people's experience is before sinking a lot of time into any given route.

So my question is, have any of you had a positive experience working with LLVM using a higher-level language and/or framework? And if so, which? Or are there any that you would say to avoid?

Comment: PyPy has abandoned LLVM quite a while ago. And even if PyPy used LLVM, it would only be used as *backend* for the interpreters and JIT-compilers created by the translation toolchain, which takes an *interpreter* written in RPython and compiles it to low-level code (optionally adding JIT and other bells and whistles along the way).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subset of LLVM API is exposed via plain C wrappers. It is sufficient for code generation, and can be used from practically any high level language. There are OCaml bindings available out of the box (see [this tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html)), and the [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/LLVM) bindings are quite mature as well (e.g., GHC itself can compile via LLVM). I've used LLVM from .NET-based languages too, without any bindings (just `P/Invoke` wrappers auto-generated from the headers).